# console error for react example webpage - a stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, ecmascript-6, jsx

The code snippet is found on the [react webpage](https://facebook.github.io/react/)

Scrolling down to **A Stateful Component**

Copy+Pasted into my codepen, this console error comes up

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Here is the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/gebrutommy/pen/rzvQxm?editors=0010)

Also here is the code itself:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {secondsElapsed: 0};
    }

    tick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          secondsElapsed: prevState.secondsElapsed + 1
        }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    } 

    render() {
        return (
          <div>Seconds Elapsed: {this.state.secondsElapsed}</div>
        );
    }

}
ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

Comment: In order to use React you need to use JSX. JSX is a language extension that compiles down to JavaScript. Your syntax error is because javascript doesn't know what to do with the html elements inside it.  http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/jsx

Answer (score 2):

> Add **Babel** as preprocessor, add node in HTML where you wish to mount the component.

```
<div id="mountNode"/>
```

Updated Link : https://codepen.io/DP888/pen/Gvdwzg?editors=1010

> As the JSX syntax and ES6, are not supported in all the browsers.Hence, if we are using them in the React code, we need to use a tool which translates them to the format that has been supported by the browsers. It’s where babel comes into the picture.